# google glass- How to implement grace period when option is selected?

Tags: android, google-glass, android-menu, google-gdk

I have read in the [GDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/design/ui/menus) that there are menu options which when get selected provide user with **Grace period to cancel there action by swiping down**.

Like the **delete option** which you get when you tap a card in Glass timeline.

I was wondering how can i implement such a menu item which has grace period ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in solution at the moment, which is a bit disappointing. Hopefully with the next update they'll add a bunch of basic functionality that should have always been in the GDK.

See https://github.com/pif/glass-progress-bar

That library is pretty feature complete and will let you do everything you want.

Comment: Thanks victor this looks like an easy alternative for now. But i hope the next GDK Update will contain this feature :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do it:

```
public static Handler MAIN_HANDLER = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private Integer pendingAction;
private Boolean isActionPending = false;
private final Long TIMEOUT = 2000; //2 seconds
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (isActionPending) {
       //TODO: better error handling
       return false;
     }
     isActionPending = true; 
    pendingAction = item.getItemId();
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.sleep(TIMEOUT);
                MAIN_HANDLER.post(
                    new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onDoPendingAction();                                    
                    }
                    }
                );
                }
}).start();

}
public void onDoPendingAction() {
   if (!isPending ) {
     return; //event was canceled
   }
   switch(pendingAction) {
     case R.id.some_menu_action: 
        //Whatever you would do.
        break;
    /* other actions */
   }
   //TODO: something to indicate teh action finished.
}
public void cancelPendingAction() {
  if (isPending) {
     isPending = false;
     //TODO: something to indicate it canceled.  
  } 
}
```

Add a gesture detector to capture the TWO_SWIPE_DOWN event and call cancelPendingAction(); if you detect it.  Get gesture detector code here.

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/touch

Comment: Thanku for the response but i wanted the complete functionality. The code that you provided works but its missing progress indicator at the bottom also i was hoping for a easy solution. Implementing grace period like this is kind of like an Overkill Right ? :)